# Xamarin Forms: Userdialogs showloading is not working in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, progressdialog

I am using [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) Nuget Package for showing the loading progress in my projects. It is working fine on android and windows, but not showing on IOS. I am using the following line of code for the progress dialog:

```
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("");
```

**Version Details:**

```
Acr.UserDialogs: 7.0.26
Xamarin forms: 4.6.0.726
```

Not added any initialization code on ios because it is optional.

For post services, the ShowLoading is working. But for the get services, there is no loading showing on the UI. I will add a sample project for the reference.

Comment: Make sure that you invoked the line in UI thread .

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: You could share your sample .As it works fine on my side .

Comment: Update the version of the plugin to the latest (7.1.x) .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have updated the plugin to the latest, but no luck and try to create a sample, but in sample no such issue. Should I update to xf version to latest?

Comment: It works on my side (plugin 7.1.x and XF 4.7.x). Of course you could update the version of XF .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of the plugin is 7.1.x . You could firstly update the plugin and XF both in Forms and platform projects .

In addition , it would be better to invoke the method in UI thread if the line is in a child tasking .

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> { 
            
   //...
            
});
```

### Update

In your sample , you invoke the line in constructor . Actually , it is not a good design . As in constructor the page hasn't finished loading yet . You could invoke the line in **OnAppearing** (you could set a property like isFirstLoad to let the dialog display one time )

Comment: In your sample , you invoke the line in constructor . Actually , it is not a good design . As in constructor the page hasn't finished loading yet . You could invoked the line in `OnAppearing` (you could set a property like isFirstLoad to let the dialog display one time )